# append an existing string with notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have multiple text files opened in Notepad++. And each file is like this.

```
[11]
[205]
[77]
```

I'm searching for `[[0-9]+]\s` in regex mode, but I don't know how to replace it to the output I need.

And I want to append a string like this in all opened files, like this.

```
[11.0]
[205.0]
[77.0]
```

I'm searching for `\[[0-9]+\]\s` in regex mode, but I don't know how to replace it to the output I need.

How to do this?

Comment: I'm searching for \[[0-9]+\]\s in regex mode, but I don't know how to replace it to the output I need.

Comment: If you don't have special cases, it does not requires regex replace. In plain text mode, just replace the `]` with `.0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\[\d+\K(?=])`
- Replace with: `.0`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\[      # openning squarre bracket
\d+     # 1 or more digits
\K      # forget all we have seen until this position
(?=])   # positive lookahead, make sure we have a closing squarre bracket after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with this code?  Find:`(\d)\b]`  Replace with:`$1.0]`

Comment: @HajiRahmatullah: It will work. But, `\b` is useless and this will modify for example `blah blah 123]`, not sure that is wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex for searching:

```
(\[\d+)(\])
```

and the following for replacing:

```
\1.0\2
```

You need to escape `[` and `]` in your pattern via a `\` since they have a special meaning in the regular expression world.